# Garageband with UVI Grand Piano

Tags: midi, garage-band

I'm trying to play a software instrument track on GarageBand and I want to use the excellent UVI Grand Piano for that. The problem is I could not get GaragaBand to recognize it as an external instrument, and there doesn't seem to be any helpful information online.

How can I connect these two? Am I missing anything or is there some intermediary software required?

Comment: Does any Daw see it?

Comment: What is a Daw?.

Comment: [Digital Audio Workstation](https://www.musicmatter.co.uk/buying-guides/daw-software)

Comment: Garageband on Mac supports VST and AU plug-ins as does the UVI Grand Piano collection. Try this video for clues to making the UVI piano set visible in the Garageband interface: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv2fOlHhmQk Let us know if this works for you.

Answer (score -3):

GarageBand is very limited, and should only be used either because you don't have money, don't have a computer, or don't want to pursue music production.

EDIT:
What I am saying is that GarageBand is probably just not capable of recognizing all external instruments. You will probably have to invest in a better DAW, or find a free one that works.

P.S.: Don't use soundflower, use iShowU Audio Capture. soundflower doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I don't want to pursue music production. I just want to enjoy what I'm doing. And unfortunately, this does not address the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35647)

Comment: @edgerunner. Sorry, I got distracted. I was meaning to write a longer answer and accidentally posted this before I was finished writing it. I have edited it for clarification.

Comment: @Richard. Sorry about that. I edited it to provide an answer.

Comment: Ethan, that's ok. To make this a good answer, consider suggesting an alternative to GarageBand that works with UVI GP, and is in a similar budget range with GB.

Comment: @EthanCannoy, there's a reason why I don't think this answers the question. Whether or not GarageBand is limited or incapable of recognizing *all* external instruments isn't being asked. The question is much more specific: can GarageBand recognize the UVI Grand Piano? It's possible for the answer to be "yes" *and* for GarageBand simultaneously to be limited in the ways you say. So your statements about GarageBand in general don't shed any light on the specific question being asked. You've said edgerunner "probably" needs a better DAW, which suggests uncertainty regarding this specific issue.

Comment: @jdjazz, sorry if I'm "necro-ing" this. I whole-heartedly agree with you. I am sure it is _possible_ to use GarageBand with a UVI Grand Piano. But it may be _improbable_. My answer was simply suggesting to get a better DAW than GarageBand. For instance, Logic Pro, FL Studio, or Audacity.